# Google Apps Script GraphQL API Call

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, graphql

I've been working with the Canvas REST API and ran into some limitations and was directed to their experimental GraphQL API. Given its experimental nature, they have little to no documentation on it. Despite its advantages for what I'm building, I can't find a whole lot on the internet either. As of right now, I can't even get a basic query to work.

```
function testsendgraphql() {
  const url = "https://hsccsd.beta.instructure.com:443/api/graphql";
  const payload = `
  query {
    course(id: 1234) {
      {
        name
      }
    }
  }`;

  const options = {
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer "+getcanvasaccesstoken() },
  "body": payload
  };
  Logger.log(query);
  apiresponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  var head = apiresponse.getAllHeaders();
  var data = JSON.parse(apiresponse.getContentText());
  Logger.log(data);
  Logger.log(head);
}
```

Running the above gets a response code of 200 but gives the following message:

```
{errors=[{message=No query string was present}]}
```

Something with my formatting of the payload seems to be off. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your script, when `body` is modified to `payload` in `options`, what result will you obtain? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) If that was not the direct solution of your issue, can you provide the official document of the API you want to use?

Comment: I didn't even realize that. I get a failed request and a 400 code now. The documentation is unfortunately limited. GraphQL is supposedly ready for Canvas but not officially so there is no official documentation on it. Here is the link to what they have https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/file.graphql.html

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that your question had been updated. When I saw your updated question, I thought that I have to apologize for my poor English skill. It seems that you modified `"body": query` to `"body": payload`. But I have proposed to modify `"body": query` to `"payload": query`. When your updated question is used, it's `"payload": payload`.

Comment: But, unfortunately, I think that your issue might not be resolved by only above modification. From your additional document, I'm still not sure about the specification of the API you want to use. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about the API you want to use, can I ask you about the sample curl command that you confirmed that you worked fine? By this, I would like to check it.

Answer (score 3):

I recently had success with the following GraphQL query using Google Apps Script:

```
function test(query) {
  var url = "https://gql.waveapps.com/graphql/public";
  var options = {"headers": {"Authorization": "Bearer " + getAccessToken(),
                             "Content-Type": "application/json"
                            },
                 "payload": JSON.stringify({query}),
                 "method": "POST"
                }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response);
  return;
}
```

where the query that was passed into the function was formatted as follows:

```
var query = "query { user { id defaultEmail } }";
```

Answer (score 0):

You must  `JSON.stringify` your query and post it as payload.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error to yours, that there was no query string present. It may be because GraphQL is looking in the URL arguments for the query, not in the HTTP request payload.

For example, get rid of the payload and change your URL to:

```
 var url = encodeURI("https://gql.waveapps.com/graphql/public?query=query{course(id:1234){{name}}}");
```

Or maybe

```
 var url = encodeURI("https://gql.waveapps.com/graphql/public?query={course(id:1234){{name}}}");
```

This was brought to my attention by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56535772/is-there-a-way-to-fetch-data-from-a-graphql-api-in-apps-script/).